# How to copy all text from the integrated vs-code terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Is there a way to copy all the text from the integrated Visual Studio Code terminal? I have some output that I want to copy to a text file and save it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can just right-click in the terminal and chose `Select All` and then right-click and `Copy`.  Does that not work for you?

There is an  unbound command for the selection:

`workbench.action.terminal.selectAll`

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for the copy.

If you do this a lot you could make a macro to do the whole thing: select, copy, open a new text file and paste.

Comment: This doesn't copy the entire output, only what's in the scroll buffer, so, if the output exceeds that, you lose it.

Answer (score 7):

If right-click in the terminal is configured to paste, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while right-clicking to bring up the contextual menu and choose *Select All* and *Copy*.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Terminal Capture](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=devwright.vscode-terminal-capture) extension to open your terminal output and open it in a tab. You can then modify and save it in any way you want.

Comment: While the accepted answer works, trying to remember `workbench.action.terminal.selectAll` is not easy. Just starting `Terminal: Capture` as `Ter` then selecting is so much nicer. Also it puts the text into a text edit tab without having to do the `Ctrl-C`,`Crtl-V` step. :)

Answer (score 5):

I moved from linux to windows and I realized many things are different. Before I could simply right click > select all > copy. On windows aparently the default behavior is to paste. So I changed my settings like this:

```
"terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior": "default"
```

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't right click in the terminal, but there's a quick open command (ctrl+shift+p) called `Terminal: Select All`

Comment: It is control + shift + P

Answer (score 3):

Another option, with VSCode 1.70 (July 2022)

[PR 153235](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/153235) (solving [issue 152097](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152097))

> ### Add command to copy output of the last command
>
> The awesome shell integration makes it really easy to rerun commands and copy the output from those commands.
>
> However, it seems one can only copy the output if the line the command was executed from is still within the scroll limit of the terminal.
> For some very long runs this is inconvenient.
>
> It would be really nice to be able to:
>
> - Copy output of last command from a terminal
> - Copy output of any command in the history of that terminal, if it is available to be copied
>
> Both without having to scroll to the point the command was executed.

You now have the `CopyLastCommand` command (`workbench.action.terminal.copyLastCommand`).
Available today in [VSCode insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

---

VsCode 1.72 (Sept. 2022) will improve the selection of the last commands (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>), for taking into acount empty commands in the terminal:

[Issue 155543](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155543):

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2193314/179614068-1a2fde2c-fd42-43e1-b957-7009bb72480b.gif]

> Currently <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>  treats "empty commands" (the circle outlines) like every other command.
>
> This would feel much nicer if they were completely skipped such that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>  would select the output of the previous non-empty command.

Solution: [PR 155551](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/155551)

> This PR implements the skipping of empty commands in the case of the terminal with non-partial command detection capabilities.
> The result is:
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/105170638/179640339-b5151cf6-5637-48d3-bbfd-4c3246d670be.gif]